# Open a fancybox while another instance of fancybox is open

Tags: jquery, fancybox

When the user clicks on a button i show a fancybox that indicates that user should wait till the action is completed:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
             $.fancybox('Please Wait...',{'modal':true});
        });
```

now i check the requested action via $.post function and return the result message (either action was successful or the error why the action failed) and now i want to close the first fancybox and show the new fancybox with the response i got from ajax:

```
$.post('someurl.aspx',{'somethingtopost':'value'},
function(data){
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
$.fancybox(data);
         });
     }
);
```

The problem is the second fancybox doesn't show. there are many examples on showing a second fancybox when closing the first one (adding to onClosed attribute) but as in this one I don't want to show the second fanybox after closing the first one, I want to show it when the action is completed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can trigger a second Fancybox any time regardless that there is one already opened (and without closing it first). Just try firing a second Fancybox when the action is completed.

The second Fancybox window (once is triggered) will replace the first one without any further closing command.

```
function openFancybox() {
    setTimeout( function() {$('#delayed').trigger('click'); },10000);
}
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#pageLoad').fancybox({
        helpers: {overlay:{opacity: 0.3}}
    }).click();
    openFancybox();
    $('#delayed').fancybox({
        helpers: {overlay:{opacity: 0.3}}
    });
}); // ready
```

I set an [example page here](http://picssel.com/playground/jquery/twoFancyboxes_04dec11.html) that starts Fancybox on page load, then it fires a second Fancybox after 10 seconds.

The first Fancybox closes automatically after the second is fired.

**UPDATE**

Or maybe you would prefer [this version](http://picssel.com/playground/jquery/twoFancyboxesBIS_04dec11.html)

```
function openFancybox() {
    setTimeout( function() {$('#delayed').trigger('click'); },10000);
}
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#goProcess').click(function(){
        $.fancybox({
            href: '#wait',
            modal: true,
            helpers: {overlay:{opacity: 0.3}},
            afterLoad: function() {
                openFancybox();
            }
        }); // fancybox
    });
    $('#delayed').fancybox({
        helpers: {overlay:{opacity: 0.3}}
    });
}); // ready
```

Open fancybox on a button click, then triggers a second fancybox after 10 seconds
(or after a process in the background is completed.)

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer and for the example that you have made. but the problem is, the second fancybox must appear after ajax returns a value and the content the new fancybox shows is the data taken from ajax response.   $.fancybox('content1); $.fancybox('content2');    here only the content1 will be shown and the second one is ignored.

Comment: As far as I understood, the first Fancybox is open on button click and the second opens with the value returned from the ajax call, if so I guess you should include  - success : function(data) {$.fancybox(data);} - in your ajax call to fire the second fancybox .... I guess you would also need - data : $(this).serializeArray() - for more than a single content field. Check http://fancybox.net/blog  No.5 for examples of how to call fancybox from an ajax call.

Comment: Just wanted to chime in and say I found this answer after getting stumped on a different problem, but with the same solution.  I was trying to close one and then open another and it was causing all sorts of errors.  Thanks @JFK