# Change fancybox Content (inline)

Tags: jquery, fancybox

i am looking for a method to change the content of the fancybox.

I have an inline Code which will be called. With the callback-function [onComplete -> $('.someClassInLayer').fancybox();] my links get fancied =).

But if i click this links nothing happens.

Can someone help me?!

Appreciate your help.

Comment: Do you mean changing the content once fancybox is already opened? or you are changing the links (bound to fancybox) dynamically before opening fancybox? ... and what version of fancybox?

Comment: I am using the newest fancybox. I want to open a "new" fancybox (means close the current and open new Content)

Comment: Understand, but you want to open the second fancybox after what action? (clicking inside the current opened fancybox for instance?  ... or else?)... and what version of fancybox?

Comment: You could also check http://stackoverflow.com/a/8379695/1055987

Comment: Thats right @JFK (clicking inside the current opened one). I use the newest version of fancybox. Checked the thread, unforunately it doesnt help me with my clicking problem, i really dont get it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything is working, i just did it on a wrong function, i am sorry.